# optimizing unreal engine 4 code

Tags: unreal-engine4

As I learning how to optimize my own code. I would imagine certain parts of unreal modules you may optimize to tune to system specifications. My main concern is I believe all the modules should have a simple on and off switch as far as choosing optimization. And to optimize my single code in it's own fashion

Answer (score 0):

You cannot tune or optimize any of the modules, they are just organizational structures for your code.

You should however make sure that your code only imports the modules you need to keep the build times low. You can do this in your [ProjectName].Build.cs file.